# How can I get angular-ui-bootstrap tabs to fill the remaining height

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a plunker to show: http://plnkr.co/edit/nGjdvrG27jNpQ3QTulMr?p=preview

I want the green area to fill the remaining available height.  I can set div height:100% and get almost I want, but that is less than desirable.

Is there a way to do this with css?  Do I need to do some sort of resizing via js?

Comment: Please, include code from external resources into your questions.

Comment: Your Fiddle example doesn't fill the remaining height: it fills more since 100% takes into account the height of tab headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've set the following classes to height: 100% and it seems to work now:

```
.tabset, .tab-content, .tab-pane, .tabbable {
  height:100%;
}
```

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sSheXC?p=preview)

Comment: Doesn't this change the total tabset height to ```.nav-tabs``` plus ```.tab-content```?

Comment: @Qi Fan I am facing the same problem, of total height being addition of .nav-tab, how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

if you use flexbox layout you can do it this way:

override the display property of the '.tab-content>.active' class. By default it is set to 'display: block'. It has to be set to 'display: flex'. Also modify the tab template.

See my solution:

[Using flexbox layout with angular-ui tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348472/using-flexbox-layout-with-angular-ui-tabs/24351947#24351947)

Comment: Wait, your answer is a link to a link to a wall of code?

Comment: what do you mean? It's a link to this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/oswSGYApFj9sSohms0FS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I know is to set the height with [`vh`](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) units. They were introduced in CSS3

```
height: 100vh;
```

[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HK1E0NKQma60gKMa9cJo?p=preview).

`vh` unit is setting the viewport height. I believe it's viewed as setting it to a % of the viewport, or visible screen. So simply changing `100%` to `100vh` gives you the desired outcome.

It seems like it's pretty widely used: http://caniuse.com/#search=vh. Just depends on who your audience base is I suppose.

Comment: Yep, this sets it to 100% of the viewport height. Unfortunately, this is greater than 100% of the .tab-content's height, so the bottom of its contents will not be viewable. The quickest way to prove this is to add a border to .tab-content as well, e.g. 'border:3px solid red;'. This may not always matter, but it does in my application.

Comment: @MichaelScheper this is true. It definitely depends on the application. Padding & Margin also play a role. Never disputed that. But it's an easy problem to solve. Start reducing the height value. 95, 90, 85, etc.

Comment: I found that CSS3 has the calc() function, which allows things like `height: calc(100% - 20px)`. Luckily, we're able to enforce clients to use modern browsers in the project I'm working on, so this solved my problem.